# SQL server syntax 1

Tags: sql-server

```
with cte4 as
(
Select a.*,(a.ADV_ART+b.ADV_ART) as A_ART
from #Temp1 a
left join #Temp1 as b
on (a.CHAT_ID = b.CHAT_ID) and (a.N = b.N + 1)
where a.Category = 2 and b.Category = 2
)
UPDATE cte4
Set ADV_ART = A_ART;
```

In this query (a.ADV_ART+b.ADV_ART) is giving null. Please help.

Comment: What are the individual values of those columns when this happens?

Comment: Horrible title, since this doesn't seem to have anything to do with syntax, and no details at all to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are strings, try: `coalesce(a.ADV_ART,'')+coalesce(b.ADV_ART,'')`

If they are numbers, try: `coalesce(a.ADV_ART,0)+coalesce(b.ADV_ART,0)`

Whenever you add or concatenate a `null` value, the result is always `null`. One of your values is returning `null`, so you can use `isnull(ValueThatMightBeNull,ReplaceWithThisValue)`
or `coalesce(ValueThatMightBeNull,ReplaceWithThisValue)` to return a different value instead of `null`.

Reference:

- [`isnull()` - msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)
- [`coalesce()` - msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

Comment: Now it's giving 0